# Customized form for registration in django not working : meta tagged model shows no error, but not working

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms

I'm trying to bootstrapify my customized registration page and fix my meta tag

Things i've tried:
I've altered the form in forms.py and added the extra fields
When I remove the meta tag from my form, it has no effect at all, so I'm assuming something's wrong around there but I can't figure out what

I'm using the inbuilt Django user model, and I've gone through many questions related to it without finding the solution. Any help would be highly appreciated !!!

Note: An important thing is, even though I've mentioned a different order in the meta tag, it doesn't reflect the tag order in the html page

Also my code shows me no errors

Here's my forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


    class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget = forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}) )
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form- 
    control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form- 
    control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name',  'email')



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SignUpForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] : 'form-control'
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] : 'form-control'
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] : 'form-control'
```

---

Here's my views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views import generic
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy
    from .forms import SignUpForm

    # Create your views here.
    class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
        form_class = SignUpForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
        template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

here's my urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import UserRegisterView

    urlpatterns = [
        path('signup/' , UserRegisterView.as_view(), name = 'signup'),

    ]
```

Here is the main page output that i'm getting

[image: Login page output]